# Is there a way to place the x axis at a specific y value in PGFPlots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I prefer single-line axes for plots, rather than the box style which is (I think) the default for PGFPlots. I'm familiar with the `axis x line*=middle` option, which places the x-axis at y=0. However, I often need to graph temperature data where it would make much more sense to show the axis at y=20 (with data in °C). I haven't been able to find a way to do this. Is there some way to make this happen?

I'd prefer not to just use a `\draw` command to manually create the axis because then I would need to manually create ticks, labels, etc.

---

Edit to clarify what I'm asking:

I'd like to achieve this, but without the kludge for the x-axis.
[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=none,
    axis y line=middle,
    xmin=0,
    ymin=5,
    ymin= 10,
    ymax=30,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    ]

    \addplot coordinates {(0,20) (1,24) (2,28) (3,18) (4,21) (5,27)};
    \coordinate (start) at (axis cs:0,20);
    \coordinate (end)   at (axis cs:5,20);
    \end{axis}

    \draw[->] (start) -- (end);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`axis x line shift` shifts x axis down, and a negative number shifts it up. From `y min=10` up to 20 gives *-10*.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=center,
        axis x line shift=-10,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=10,
        ymax=30,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,20) (1,24) (2,28) (3,18) (4,21) (5,27)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with x-axis at y=20]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!